# STM32 HAL timer interrupt isn't triggered

Tags: timer, interrupt, stm32, interrupt-handling, hal

I'm trying to periodically send and Serial string from my STM32F746ZG device, using an interrupt. Most of the code is auto generated by stm32cubemx. I have hardware breakpoints (jlink) set at each interrupt but I only enter the period elapse function once, at initialization. When I randomly pause the debugger I see the counter values between 0 and 1000 as expected. So I know the counter resets every second. The internal clock runs at 16MHz.

My experience with embedded devices is limited to BBB, Raspberry and Arduino's. I tried different examples and tutorials, but at the moment I just don't know anymore. Any help or suggestions is much appreciated.

my main function:

```
int main(void) {

    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_RTC_Init();
    MX_TIM1_Init();

    if (HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim1) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    if (HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim1) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    while (1) {
        cnt = __HAL_TIM_GetCounter(&htim1);
    }
}
```

TIM1 init:

```
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void) {

    TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
    TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;

    htim1.Instance = TIM1;
    htim1.Init.Prescaler = 16000;
    htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
    htim1.Init.Period = 1000;
    htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
    htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0x0;
    if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
    if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim1, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
    sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger2 = TIM_TRGO2_RESET;
    sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig)
            != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

}
```

My Base_MspInit function:

```
void HAL_TIM_Base_MspInit(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim_base)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  if(htim_base->Instance==TIM1)
  {
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_TIM1_CLK_ENABLE();
    /* Peripheral interrupt init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM1_BRK_TIM9_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM1_BRK_TIM9_IRQn);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQn);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM11_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM11_IRQn);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM1_CC_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM1_CC_IRQn);
  }
}
```

My TIM IRQ handler function:

```
void TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim1);
}
```

HAL IRQ Handler which calls the HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback:

```
void HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
  /* Capture compare 1 event */
  if(__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_CC1) != RESET)
  {
    if(__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_CC1) !=RESET)
    {
      {
        __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_CC1);
        htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_1;

        /* Input capture event */
        if((htim->Instance->CCMR1 & TIM_CCMR1_CC1S) != 0x00)
        {
          HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(htim);
        }
        /* Output compare event */
        else
        {
          HAL_TIM_OC_DelayElapsedCallback(htim);
          HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(htim);
        }
        htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_CLEARED;
      }
    }
  }
  /* Capture compare 2 event */
  if(__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_CC2) != RESET)
  {
    if(__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_CC2) !=RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_CC2);
      htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_2;
      /* Input capture event */
      if((htim->Instance->CCMR1 & TIM_CCMR1_CC2S) != 0x00)
      {          
        HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(htim);
      }
      /* Output compare event */
      else
      {
        HAL_TIM_OC_DelayElapsedCallback(htim);
        HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(htim);
      }
      htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_CLEARED;
    }
  }
  /* Capture compare 3 event */
  if(__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_CC3) != RESET)
  {
    if(__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_CC3) !=RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_CC3);
      htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_3;
      /* Input capture event */
      if((htim->Instance->CCMR2 & TIM_CCMR2_CC3S) != 0x00)
      {          
        HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(htim);
      }
      /* Output compare event */
      else
      {
        HAL_TIM_OC_DelayElapsedCallback(htim);
        HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(htim); 
      }
      htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_CLEARED;
    }
  }
  /* Capture compare 4 event */
  if(__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_CC4) != RESET)
  {
    if(__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_CC4) !=RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_CC4);
      htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_4;
      /* Input capture event */
      if((htim->Instance->CCMR2 & TIM_CCMR2_CC4S) != 0x00)
      {          
        HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(htim);
      }
      /* Output compare event */
      else
      {
        HAL_TIM_OC_DelayElapsedCallback(htim);
        HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(htim);
      }
      htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_CLEARED;
    }
  }
  /* TIM Update event */
  if(__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_UPDATE) != RESET)
  {
    if(__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_UPDATE) !=RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_UPDATE);
      HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(htim);
    }
  }
  /* TIM Break input event */
  if(__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_BREAK) != RESET)
  {
    if(__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_BREAK) !=RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_BREAK);
      HAL_TIMEx_BreakCallback(htim);
    }
  }

    /* TIM Break input event */
  if(__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_BREAK2) != RESET)
  {
    if(__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_BREAK) !=RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_BREAK);
      HAL_TIMEx_BreakCallback(htim);
    }
  }

  /* TIM Trigger detection event */
  if(__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_TRIGGER) != RESET)
  {
    if(__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_TRIGGER) !=RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_TRIGGER);
      HAL_TIM_TriggerCallback(htim);
    }
  }
  /* TIM commutation event */
  if(__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_COM) != RESET)
  {
    if(__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_COM) !=RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_FLAG_COM);
      HAL_TIMEx_CommutationCallback(htim);
    }
  }
}
```

My callback function:

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim) {
    if (htim->Instance == TIM1) {
        char frame[20] = "123456789012345678\r\n";
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, frame, 20, 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code above was correct. The break points were "temporary hardware" breakpoints, when I changed them to "hardware" breakpoints they where hit when there was a counter overflow indicating that the period was reached.

Typical case of staring at the same code for far too long ;-)

Comment: how to change them to hardware?